# .NET WinForm Memory Consumption

Tags: vb.net, winforms, memory

I've been profiling a WinForm's application using ".NET Memory Profiler".

I can't quite seem to understand how my application is growing to 1GB, then 2GB, then 3GB of usage - according to windows task manager.

The private bytes using that tool, and "Total Bytes in All Heaps" shows only as 70MB or so. At the top of my list of instances hanging around, they are mostly String, or WeakReferences to lots of little objects.

All the application is doing is showing a form that loads data from a database. I repeat the show/dispose cycle of the form about 100 times and the growth is continuous.

I've tried about 3 memory profiling tools now and none of them are showing me where this enormous amount of memory consumption is coming from.

Can anyone help or take a guess as to what it might be?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you profiling an executable or the debug version from your IDE?

Comment: I'm profiling the EXE built in Debug mode, not via the IDE.

Comment: Is this actually an app written in vb.net?  Then the WeakReference leak is expected.

Comment: Yes, a VB .NET app based in .NET 2.0.

Comment: @Hans Passant. Is this a known issue for VB.NET apps? Do you happen to have any article links?

Comment: @Conrad http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=919481

Answer (score 5):

> Is this a known issue for VB.NET apps?

Yes.  It is a side-effect of Edit + Continue support compiled into the executable.  It is affected by any event that is declared with the WithEvents keyword.  A WeakReference keeps track of those event instances.  Problem is, those WeakReferences are leaked if you run the app without a debugger.  The rate at which the process consumes memory is highly dependent on how many instances of the class get created.  The leak is 16 bytes per event per object.

The workaround is simple, do *not* use the Debug build of your app without a debugger.  Only use the Release build.  And of course, only ship the Release build to your customer.

Comment: +1. Here is a link to the relevant [Microsoft KnowledgeBase article](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=919481), just for completeness. It doesn't add anything to Hans's answer

Comment: As you might know, in the release build the symbolic debug info is not emitted and the code execution is optimized and this way the size of the final executable is smaller than the debug executable. BUT, first check the settings (how the symbolic debug info is emitted) you have specified in Debug and Release configurations (Right click your win forms project -> Properties -> Build tab -> Advanced... -> Debug Info setting), and think then what you want them to be.

Answer (score 4):

> I can't quite seem to understand how my application is growing to 1GB, then 2GB, then 3GB of usage - according to windows task manager.

That's because the counter from task manager is the "working set" as Tess Ferrandez points out in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/09/06/742568.aspx)

> There is another counter called
>   working set which simplified consists
>   of how much memory is in the memory
>   pages that are currently or was
>   recently touched by threads in the
>   process or approximately, how much of
>   the memory that is used by the process
>   is currently in RAM.  The working set
>   counter might be interesting if you
>   have issues with too much paging and
>   many processes on the same box
>   competing about the RAM, but in order
>   to determine how much memory you are
>   using (reserved or committed) it
>   offers little or no help.

From the [MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997156%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx) on working set (Emphasis mine)

> **Working Set**
>
> The set of memory pages
>   (areas of memory allocated to a
>   process) recently used by the threads
>   in a process. If available memory on
>   the server is above a specified
>   threshold, **pages remain in the Working Set of a process even if they are not in use**. When available memory falls
>   below a specified threshold, pages are
>   removed from the Working Set. If these
>   pages are needed, they will be
>   returned back to the Working Set
>   before they leave main memory and are
>   made available for other processes to
>   use.

Comment: Thanks for that Conrad. What I can't understand is how windows is allowing it consume so much RAM when it's only running on a 3GB max RAM box. With Visual Studio open and lot's of others things going on, it's certainly spilling over the amount of available RAM. I've never seen this kind of behavior in non-managed languages, surely it's unreasonable? Visual Studio running for days only consumes 400mb for me on average.

Comment: @MeshMan my guess is that you don't have any other Processes competing for RAM so its not trimming the working set and you probably have a very large Page File

Answer (score 0):

I have found that under high CPU load that the garbage collection often gets a very low priority so the .NET libraries responsible for cleaning up unused memory will only fire off when they absolutely have to, in spite of the reference counts to a managed object going to zero.  If it's possible try putting some intentional Thread.Sleep calls in your code *or* simply accept the fact that it's a memory hog and hope that the logic will allow your system to run and it will have "odd" memory usage as you never stated that anything breaks, it just has an unreal memory footprint.