# Explicit Local Scopes - Any True Benefit?

Tags: c#, scope

I was cleaning up some code and removed an `if` statement that was no longer necessary. However, I realized I forgot to remove the brackets. This of course is valid and just created a new local scope. Now this got me thinking. In all my years of C# development, I have never come across a reason to use them. In fact, I kind of forgot I could do it.

Is there any actual benefit to defining a local scope? I understand I can define variables in one scope and then define the same ones again in an unrelated scope (for, foreach, etc.) like below:

```
void SomeMethod()
{    
    {
        int i = 20;
    }
    
    int i = 50; //Invalid due to i already being used above.
}

void SomeMethod2()
{    
    {
        int i = 20;
    }
    {
        int i = 50; //Valid due to scopes being unrelated.
    }
    {
        string i = "ABCDEF";
    }
}
```

What's the true point of defining a local scope? Can there actually be any sort of performance gain (or potentially a loss)? I know you could do this in C++ and was part of helping you manage memory, but because this is .NET, would there really be a benefit? Is this just a by-product of the language that let's us define random scopes even though there is no true benefit?

Comment: +1, it's surpised that C# compiler allows `{}` without `if`, don't know is there any reason for this

Comment: besides being able to reuse same variable name, I cant see any :(

Comment: If you find yourself in a place where this is useful - you should probably be breaking up the code into separate methods...

Comment: @Oded That's kind of my thought. I definitely wouldn't use this to just reuse variable names. I like my descriptive names  =)

Comment: [case 3 here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/13/four-switch-oddities.aspx) is one place they might be useful.

Comment: @MartinSmith That might be worth expanding on and posting as an answer since that is actually a legitimate use for an explicit scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C#, it is purely syntax to turn a group of statements into a single statement.  Required for any keyword that expects a single statement to follow, like if, for, using, etc.  A few corner cases:

- the *case* keyword inside a switch is special since it doesn't require it to be a single statement.  The *break* or *goto* keyword ends it.  Which explains why you can use braces to jam in a variable declaration.
- the *try* and *catch* keywords are special, they *require* braces even if only a single statement follows.  Pretty unusual but probably inspired by forcing the programmer to think about the scope of declarations inside the blocks, a catch block cannot refer to variables inside the try block because of the way exception handling works.

Limiting the scope of local variables with it is a lost cause.  It is a big deal in C++ because the ending brace is the place where the compiler will inject destructor calls for variables inside the scope block.  This is ab/used all the time for the RAII pattern, nothing terribly pretty about having punctuation in a program have such drastic side-effects.

The C# team didn't have a lot of choice about it, the life-time of local variables is strictly controlled by the jitter.  Which is oblivious to any grouping constructs inside a method, it only knows about IL.  Which doesn't have any grouping constructs beyond try/except/finally.  The scope of any local variable, no matter where it was written, is the body of the method.  Something you can see when you run ildasm.exe on compiled C# code, you'll see the local variables hoisted to the top of the method body.  Which partly also explains why the C# compiler won't let you declare another local variable in another scope block with the same name.

The jitter has interesting rules about local variable lifetime, they are entirely dominated by how the garbage collector works.  When it jits a method, it doesn't just generate the machine code for the method but also creates a table that describes the actual scope of every local variable, the code address where it is initialized and the code address where it is no longer used.  The garbage collector uses that table to decide if a reference to an object is valid, based on the active execution address.

Which makes it *very* efficient at collecting objects.  A little too efficient sometimes and troublesome when you interop with native code, you may need the magic GC.KeepAlive() method to extend the lifetime.  A very remarkable method, it doesn't generate any code at all.  Its only use is to get the jitter to change the table and insert a larger address for the variable life-time.

Comment: The lexical scope may be the method, but just to emphasize, the GC doesn't care about that.  Once you stop using it the GC can take it away, even if it's in the middle of the method, even if it's in the middle of a method call on the object itself.  This is why GC.KeepAlive is important.

Comment: Also this is legal, though I can't format it:
M()
{
{
int x = 5;
Console.WriteLine(x);
}
{
int x = 6;
Console.WriteLine(x);
}
}

Answer (score 6):

Just like functions, these "blocks" are pretty much just to isolate regions of (mostly) unrelated code and their local variables within a function.

You might use it if you needed some temporary variable just to pass between two function calls, for example

```
int Foo(int a) {

    // ...

    {
        int temp;
        SomeFuncWithOutParam(a, out temp);

        NowUseThatTempJustOnce(temp);            
    }

    MistakenlyTryToUse(temp);    // Doesn't compile!

    // ...

}
```

One might aruge, however, that if you need this kind of lexical scoping, the inner blocks should be functions on their own anyway.

As for performance, etc. I highly doubt it matters at all.  The compiler looks at the function as a whole, and collects *all* local variables (even ones declared in-line), when determining the stack frame size.  So basically all local variables are lumped together anyway.  It's a purely lexical thing to give you a little more constraint on your variables' usage.

Comment: The example you gave isn't a good one.  The C# compiler doesn't allow you to declare a *temp* variable before nor after the block.  So there's no point in using the block.

Comment: @HansPassant why couldn't it be before the block, at the top of the function?

Comment: If "it" means "another variable named temp" then that's because it doesn't compile.  Have you tried it?  I explained it partially in my answer.

Comment: Ah, your edit explains. (It's too late to edit my comment.) Right, you can't re-use variable names in inner and outer scopes. My whole point of that example is that the block *prevents* you from using temp anywhere outside of the block.

Answer (score 3):

There is place where local scopes could be useful: inside `case` statements of a `switch` statement. All cases share by default the same scope as the `switch` statement. 
Declaring a local temporary variable with the same name inside multiple `case` statements is not allowed, and you could end up with declaring the variable only in the first case-statement or even outside the `switch`-statement.
You can solve this problem by giving each case statement a local scope and declare the temporary variable inside the scope.
However don't make your cases too complex, this problem might be an indication that it's better to call a separate method to handle the `case`-statement.

Comment: A code example showing how it is useful would be very helpful here

Answer (score 2):

The advantage is mostly that it makes the definition of the language simpler.

The definiton can now simply state that if, while, for, etc.. should be followed by a single statement. A set of statements within parentheses is simply one more possible kind of statement.

There is no real gain by forbidding statement blocks as used in your example. Sometimes they are useful to avoid name clashes but you could solve your problem without. It would also unneccesarily introduce a difference in syntax rules as compared to languages like C, C++ and Java.

In case you wonder it also does not change the object lifetimes of the referenced objects.

Answer (score 0):

There won't be a performance gain, at least in release mode: the GC can collect an object if it knows - or at least thinks - it will no longer be used, regardless of scope.  This can screw you with unmanaged interop: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/13/10049634.aspx.

That said, I use this "feature" from time to time to ensure that code later in the method can't use some temporary object.  In most cases it could probably be accomplished by splitting into additional methods, but occasionally that gets unnecessarily unwieldy, or is for some reason impossible (e.g. in a constructor where you are setting readonly members).  And once in a while I use it to be able to reuse variable names but that's usually coupled with the "temporary object" reason.

Comment: Your first paragraph goes directly against Hans' answer.

Comment: Please elaborate. If you're referring to my "release mode" qualifier, the compiler adds nops so you can put breakpoints on the braces in Debug mode. Hans himself says that here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13752156/155892

Comment: No, where you said it is eligible for GC collection when it goes out of scope. In code, "scope" is the local block. But Hans stated in his answer that all local variables are hoisted to function scope, regardless of local blocks. Which means they won't be eligible for GC until the function returns.

Comment: Hmm, rereading your paragraph a couple of times has left me confused though now :-P

Comment: Now I see where things seem to diverge between me and Hans. Hans is talking about the scope in which you _can_ use a variable, but I am talking about the scope in which the GC cares that you _are using_ a variable.  In other words, I am saying that the scope in which a variable *can* be used doesn't matter to performance. Take a look at this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/10/10048149.aspx