# Is it reasonable to use curly brackets as a form of code block markers to indicate which block of code a comment is reffering to?

Tags: java, c#

Since you can put `{}` anywhere in your code (for Java and C# at very least) without it changing anything in terms of execution of the code, would be unreasonable to say you could then use them as a 'fence' to demarcate different operational steps of a function?

i.e:

```
private int foo(int bar)
{
    ...
    // some prior code here
    ...
    { // BLOCK A - this section creates a bad example of recursion
        bar = foo(bar) * 2;
    }

    { // BLOCK B - this block is to further illustrate my point
        if(bar > 0)
        {
            bar *= -1;
        }
    }
    ...
    // some more code here
    ...

}
```

Or is there some kind of hidden optimization issue that this will be the root cause of in the compiler?

Edit:
To simplify my question, can curly braces be used as a more visual way of identifying exactly which lines of code a comment pertains to.

How this is different to the below link, that link is asking about internal scope inside a local scope. I am asking purely for decoration and readability sake.

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871395/explicit-local-scopes-any-true-benefit

Comment: @Renat I don't believe it is related to that post, as that is asking about a different use case to it. My question is asking whether you can use the braces to indicate the block of code a comment is talking about, as a way to group thing together in a more visual way.

Comment: What you should consider is: Couldn't this code block just as well be a separate method? When it is such a distinct section that it merits its dedicated comment, then it may likely be worth a method too. P.s. what I personally like to do (when a dedicated method means too many arguments to be passed) is to a have quad-slash comment to denote a section (think of \n as new lines): 
//// The answer to everything  \n 
a = 42; \n 
////

Comment: Using code blocks for this is a misuse, in my books. It's not only a visual bracketing, it is also syntactically and otherwise relevant. For example variable scopes. In C#, an **alternative** could be `#region` / `#endregion` , though? => See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#defining-regions

Comment: @Fildor I completely forgot about regions before asking about this. They do seem to make the code a lot more readable, and it's easier to spot than some braces around the code. But at the same time, using a region inside of a function seems excessive...

Comment: Well, some people would consider an additional code block for - or even comments like that excessive.

Comment: ^^ What I have done in the past, where an especially complex piece of code needed documentation to not be constantly the target of "simplification" attempts that were futile and never lead to simpler, _working_ code: I put a link to a Markdownfile in the code. The file resided next to the code file with the same name (just .md extension instead .cs of course). Inside it had all the explanations, references and code was cited, where needed, in code blocks. It also had BenchmarkDotnet Tables to _show_ how and which past "optimization" attempts failed.

Comment: Also: _"without it changing anything in terms of execution of the code"_ - that's a false premise, _at least_ for C#.

Comment: @Fildor How so? Is it not only changing the scope of the variables declared within the braces? Or is there more to it than that?

Comment: According to the question linked by Renat, in C# it will make zero-difference, as the lifetime of a variable is to the method scope, even if its actual usage is restricted to a block. I'm not sure how accurate it is. I know that in Java, judicious use of blocks may in some cases result in the generated byte code using less slots than if you leave the blocks out (without blocks, slots may also be reused!). However, in practice this will hardly make a difference, and when it comes to JIT it might even be harder to specify a benefit of doing it. In general, don't use blocks just because you can.

Comment: BTW: This also demonstrates why you should not tag more than one language. Even though the syntax of Java and C# may be similar, their implementation differs at a lot of points, so conclusions for Java don't necessarily apply for C# and vice versa.

Comment: ^^ Also, there may be solutions that will only work for one and if you answer with it, you'll always get dv'ed for the lacking one. So you'll not get _any_ answer.

Comment: _"How so?"_ - In your example, it will not. But _generally_ you can't just go around adding blocks "at random" and not expect bugs to emerge.

Comment: On a related note, some cargo-culters will use blocks because they say it "helps" the garbage collector. If the question linked by Renat is accurate, that benefit doesn't exist in C#, and in Java it might help, but only if the slot gets reused *after* the block, for another variable, otherwise the slot will strongly reference the object until method end (and again, JIT will throw everything about this out, and might release the reference earlier, but also later, so you can't reliably reason about the benefits).